# Wrapping text an image in itext7

Tags: itext

iText5 had a simple way to run text around an Image - by using

```
img.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
```

But this doesn't appear to be supported in iText7. Or is there some other way?